# How to invoke a onclick event on specific dynamic button on javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I am working on a usercontrol file which contains a textbox and a button.

The control renders multiple records on one page and hence creating and rendering the textboxes and buttons dynamically.

I am trying to invoke a javascript function to validate whether the textbox has value. My problem is I am not able to determine which button is being clicked as it is dynamically created. (As I am integrating this control in parent page gridview and hence it becomes dynamic.)

Please advise community. What I am assuming is I am not able to set the index to the button Id I am retrieving before calling the `closure`.

I tried following few links available on this website but finally I have post my issue here to seek specific answer.

Below is my code snipeet.

**HTML:**

```js
function validateSubmit() {
            var btn = document.getElementsByClassName('frmBtn').length;
            var btnId = document.getElementById('<%=commentSubmitButton.ClientID%>').id;
            
            for (var j = 1; j <= btn; j++) {
                (function(j){
                    
                    btnId[j].onclick = function(){
                        alert('INSIDE CLICK');
                        
                        var e = document.getElementsByClassName('frmTextBox')[j].value;
                        if (e == '') {
                            document.getElementsByClassName('lbl')[j].style.display = 'block';
                        }
                    }
                })(j);
            }
    }
```

```html
<div class="frmContent">
 <p style="float: right; padding-top: 2em;">
  <asp:Button ID="commentSubmitButton" runat="server" Text="Submit" CssClass="frmBtn" OnClientClick="validateSubmit(this);" />
 
 </p>
 <p>
  <label for="txtComment" class="frmLabels">
   Type Comment Here
   
   <label id="lblStar" class="lbl" style="display:none;color:red;">*</label>
  </label>
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtComment" runat="server" Height="60" Width="75%" TextMode="MultiLine" CssClass="frmTextBox" ></asp:TextBox>
 </p>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

Comment: There are probably different ways of doing this. If it were me, I'd take advantage of the fact that click events bubble upwards. So I would not attach onclick events to the individual elements but to a common parent , with onclick="myfunction(event)". The event object would tell you which element was actually clicked (using event.target).

Comment: I guess you are taking me closer to my issue. Can you please provide relevant snippet to my issue? I appreciate your inputs.

Comment: I apologize since I can't quite understand from your code what your final HTML will look like, but, for example you could attach   onclick="myfunction(event)"  to your top-level div. If anything inside the div is clicked, the event will bubble up to the div. You could encode the IDs of the dynamic elements so that you could tell which button was clicked, and, from its ID, know how to find the related textbox. For example the button could have ID="button_1" while the textbox has ID="textbox_1". Just make sure to keep IDs unique on the page. Sorry I couldn't be more clear.

Comment: Thank you for the elaboration. Can you provide more direction on how to find the textbox relevant to the particular button clicked ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I figured it out.

I wonder why I kept inclining toward conventional JavaScript approach when such things can be achieved easily with so nice and so advanced jquery. I observed few concepts on [jquery](http://jqueryui.com/) and it helped me made this little thing work in very few lines. Here is the relevant code I wrote with jquery.

It is working now satisfactorily. Thank you all.

**jquery code**

```
function validateSubmit(btnid) 
{
        //debugger;
        var txtbox = $(btnid).parent().parent().find('.frmTextBox')[0];
        var lblRequired = $(btnid).parent().parent().find('.lbl')[0];

        if (txtbox.value == '') {
            lblRequired.style.display = 'block';
            event.preventDefault();
        } else {
            lblRequired.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
```